# How to declare Java final variable so it define a range or domain of valid integer values?

Tags: java, variables

Is there a way to declare final java variable so it would represent a range of valid values.

**Example 1:** Integer values from 1 to 99 .

**Example 2:** All Fibonacci numbers in a given range.
I need this kind of variable to be able to quickly make a decision if tested value is in some predefined range / domain.

Comment: Other than specifying variable width there is no way to specify a constraint on a Java primitive value.

Comment: Are you asking for a compile-time or runtime check?

Comment: For current task I need compile-time check. But how would approach differ with run-time check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example 1 I think that a standard greater-than or less-than test will be quicker than any lookup, as a lookup is also going to be a comparison of integers.

For example 2 your only real option is a `Set<Integer>` which contains the acceptable values, unless there is a function that tests whether a number is Fibonnaci or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like

```
interface Domain<T> {
    boolean contains(T t);
}
```

then, a possible implementation might be

```
public IntegerRange implements Domain<Integer> {
    private final int lower;
    private final int upper;

    public IntegerRange(int lower, int upper) {
        this.lower = lower;
        this.upper = upper;
    }

    public boolean contains(Integer i) {
        return i >= lower && i <= upper;
    }
}
```

**For Fibonacci**, after [GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-number-fibonacci-number/)

```
public FibonacciDomain implements Domain<Integer> {

    private boolean isPerfectSquare(int x) {
        int s = Math.sqrt(x);
        return (s*s == x);
    }

    public boolean contains(Integer n) {
        return isPerfectSquare(5*n*n + 4) || isPerfectSquare(5*n*n - 4);
    } 

}
```

**Example:**

```
public class MyClass {
    private final Domain<Integer> domain = IntegerRange(42,1337);

    public void secret(int codez) {
        if(domain.contains(codez)) {
          System.out.println("You may pass"); 
        }
    }

}
```

You can combine both ranges to form one that you want.